Using CSVHelper Getting Exceptions with unexpected columns
I am importing data from a 3rd party and only require a few of the fields/columns in the CSV.
The file has the header row:
id  created_time    ad_id   ad_name adset_id    adset_name  campaign_id campaign_name   form_id form_name   is_organic  platform    full_name   email   phone_number    date_of_birth   lead_status
I am only interested in importing a few of these and have the initialization as follows:
These are the classes describing the fields/columns I want, and the Mapper I thought would make it ignore the rest.
public class CSVFileVars
{
    public string? full_name { get; set; }

    public string? email { get; set; }

    public string? phone_number { get; set; }

    public DateTime date_of_birth { get; set; }
}

public sealed class CSVFileVarsMap : ClassMap<CSVFileVars>
{
    public CSVFileVarsMap()
    {
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}

This is my code:
...
StreamReader reader;
List<CSVFileVars> records = new List<CSVFileVars>();
reader = new StreamReader(memStrm);
var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
{
   // NewLine = Environment.NewLine,
    Delimiter = ",",
    HeaderValidated = null,
    MissingFieldFound = null,
    IgnoreBlankLines = false,
    HasHeaderRecord = true
};
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader,config ))
{
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CSVFileVarsMap>();
    var nonlistrecords =  csv.GetRecords<CSVFileVars>();  <--No Exception
    records = csv.GetRecords<CSVFileVars>().ToList();  <--THrows Exception

UPDATE
Answering some of the valid points below:
It works if I strip out the unused columns from the source csv file.
I'll come to the exception in a minute, but here is a sample csv that breaks it. (I have changed the raw data so it doesnt represent anything real, I have also reduced the columns to a minimum not working example):
id,created_time,ad_id,is_organic,platform,full_name,email,phone_number,date_of_birth,lead_status
l:1156662815489222,2024-05-17T15:34:04+01:00,ag:120208857852060391,FALSE,fb,John Doe,jdo@gmail.com,p:+44712345,06/21/1989,complete
l:1606325686856333,2024-05-17T14:35:29+01:00,ag:120208857852060391,FALSE,fb,Jane Doeless,Jdoless@ntlworld.com,p:+44234567,02/03/1952,complete

I have also modified the CSVFileVarsMap to make my own class objects optional:
public sealed class CSVFileVarsMap : ClassMap<CSVFileVars>
{
    public CSVFileVarsMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.created_time).Optional();
        Map(m => m.full_name).Optional();
        Map(m => m.email).Optional();
        Map(m => m.phone_number).Optional();
        Map(m => m.date_of_birth).Optional();
        AutoMap(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    }
}

More Research with this sample is showing some kind of Type conversion exception.
So I added an addiitonal line to get the records without making a list:
var nonlistrecords =  csv.GetRecords<CSVFileVars>();

This line doesn't throw an exception, but the following line :
records = csv.GetRecords<CSVFileVars>().ToList();

throws this exception:

The conversion cannot be performed.
Text: ''
MemberName: created_time
MemberType: System.DateTime
TypeConverter: 'CsvHelper.TypeConversion.DateTimeConverter'
IReader state:
ColumnCount: 10
CurrentIndex: 1
HeaderRecord:
["id","created_time","ad_id","is_organic","platform","full_name","email","phone_number","date_of_birth","lead_status"]
IParser state:
ByteCount: 0
CharCount: 384
Row: 4
RawRow: 4
Count: 10
RawRecord:
,,,,,,,,,

I have also discovered that if I swap the first and second columns around, then it works! I was led to try this because of the conversion error implication in the exception.
So I can't decide if this is bug in the lib or just something in my set-up. Given the provenance of the lib and the number of users it must be my set-up mustn't it?

When you say 'strip out the columns that are not being used' do you mean adding Map(p => p.PropertyNameExample).Ignore();?

The screenshot show the CallStack of the Inner Exception. The CallStack for the actual ReaderException should be more telling. Hit the "Show Call Stack"  BUtton in the shown Dialog. And please if what you see then does not help you add it to your question here as Text not as Picture and not in the comments.

@stuartd. No. I mean go into the csv file and delete the columns.

@Ralf.. so are you saying my code looks OK and should work?. I'll look and post again tomorrow but I am curious..

Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically a CSV sample (as text, not as a screen shot) that we can use to debug your problem, as suggested in [ask]?  The full ToString() output of the exception including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any, might also help.  Thanks!

My question is what is RaffleGames.Shared.Models.Organization and does it have anything to do with the 3rd party data you are pulling in? I don't see any reason why it would attempt to use that class from the code you have shown.

Yes @DavidSpecht, that was my point about it 'casting around' ...  The Organisation object has nothing whatsoever to do with this function and is not references anywhere in this controller. (It is an API controller). The 3rd Party data is from a Facebook form and also has nothing to do with the organisation object. - Which is why I think it is odd...

Your updated CSVFileVarsMap class does not compile, because CSVFileVars lacks a created_time member.  If I add public DateTime created_time { get; set; } then your code works correctly and successfully deserializes the CSV shown in your question, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/Z97ypn.  If you are still experiencing problems, please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].  Otherwise your question can be closed as no longer reproducible.  Thanks!

Incidentally, csvReader.GetRecords<T>() uses streaming deferred excution.  I.e. the file isn't actually read until you iterate over the IEnumerable<T> returned by GetRecords<T>().  That's why csv.GetRecords<CSVFileVars>(); will not throw an exception even if csv.GetRecords<CSVFileVars>().ToList() does -- the former doesn't actually read anything.

OK... so why does putting the date field first or changing the order cause it not to have the exception?

@BrettJB - I can't reproduce an exception with the CSV shown in your question.  If you would [edit] the question to include a CSV sample that throw, we could probably tell you why.  Thanks.

ok thanks @dbc .. This code is part of a controller and to be honest I don't really know how I could reduce it to the bare bones to get it on here. Anyway, I've decided to take the easy if less satisfactory way out and switched to a different lib that does work. Thanks everyone.

@BrettJB - OK.  One final point: I haven't checked this, but my impression is that AutoMap() overwrites the previous manual mappings.  Try moving the calls to Map(m => m.created_time).Optional(); after the call to AutoMap().  The docs show the manual mapping coming after AutoMap().
